# Copy a file from s3 to GCP object storage by piping or streaming get from s3 to put in cloud storage

Tags: python, amazon-s3, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, bytesio

Is it possible to make an API call to S3 to fetch a file and then pipe the result into an API call to GCP cloud storage(Object storage) to put an object. This will effectively copy the file from S3 to Azure blob.

My goal is to do this completely in-memory without writing anything to disk and also being able to handle files larger than memory.
Is this even possible?

I have tried looking in the python docs for any such option but did not find any. I did come across BytesIO which may be helpful.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Are there any reasons to avoid Cloud Storage Transfer Service - https://cloud.google.com/storage-transfer/docs/overview ? which can work with AWS S3 bucekts - https://cloud.google.com/storage-transfer/docs/source-amazon-s3 ?

Answer (score 0):

Sure, Google Cloud Storage's `gsutil` can copy between clouds. Once you install it and [configure it](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil_install#authenticate) with your GCP credentials, open up the ".boto" file and add a section with your AWS credentials:

```
[Credentials]
aws_access_key_id = ACCESS_KEY_ID
aws_secret_access_key = SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
```

Then run a copy command, like so:

```
gsutil cp s3://mybucket/myblob gs://mybucket/myblob
```

If it's a whole lot of files, you may want to run `gsutil` on a GCE or EC2 instance so that the data doesn't need to stream through your local machine.

Alternately, if you need to do this for very large buckets or on a regular schedule, you could look into the Storage Transfer Service, which can perform large copies from S3: https://cloud.google.com/storage-transfer-service

Answer (score 0):

First, you should consider if you want to develop your own code for this. There are many options to move from AWS S3 to GCP CS.

Also consider that GCP CS can be treated as a S3 bucket with the compatibility API, so any option valid from moving from one S3 bucket to another S3 bucket should work also between AWS S3 and GCP CS.

That said, if you still want to code your own implementation, and you do not want to store the file locally, you could use the multipart download & upload to chain it: https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#multipartupload

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to copy data between S3 and google cloud storage is [Skyplane](https://github.com/skyplane-project/skyplane). Skyplane doesn't write data to disk between transfers. To get setup, run:

```bash
pip install skyplane # install skyplane 
skyplane init # provide cloud credentials
```

Then, you can transfer data with:

```bash
skyplane cp s3://aws-bucket-name/my_obj gcs://google-bucket-name/my_obj
```

Although `gsutil` and `aws cp` can also theoretically transfer between cloud buckets, you will have to change your bucket permissions to allow access from another cloud account. These tools are also quite slow and won't work for larger objects or total transfer sizes.